# Zoom-in to by coordinates of location in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, zoom

I'm trying to zoom in to location by coordinates after click on one item from autocomplete list.

```
    $("#template-custom").easyAutocomplete({
        url: "Toponimos-red.json",
        getValue: function(element) {
            return element.Nombre;
        },
        template: {
            type: "custom",
            method: function(value, item) {
                return  value + " , " + item.Tipo;
            }
        },

        list: {
            match: {
                enabled: true
            },
            maxNumberOfElements: 20,

            onChooseEvent: function() {
                    var selectedItemCoordX = $("#template-custom").getSelectedItemData().CoordX;
                    var selectedItemCoordY = $("#template-custom").getSelectedItemData().CoordY;
                    var valcoordx=parseFloat(selectedItemCoordX);
                    var valcoordy=parseFloat(selectedItemCoordY);

                    var coordinate= [valcoordx, valcoordy];

                    console.log(valcoordx, "-", valcoordy, "-", valcoordx+valcoordy, "-", coordinate);

                    map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:25830', 'EPSG:3857'));
                    map.getView().setZoom(10);

            },
        },
        theme: "round"
    });
```

I know that the problem is:

```
 map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:25830', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

Because if I remove this line, the zoom runs.

Why doesn´t it work?  What is the problem?

I have been doing some tests and the problem is the transformation from EPSG:25830 TO EPSG:3857.  If I do the same but the coordinates are in EPSG:3857 it works.

How can I do it with EPSG:25830?

Must I add the plugin proj4?

Answer (score 1):

Is seems you've find the problem and the solution yourself, good !
As far as  I know Openlayers only handles EPSG 3857 and 4326, so if you need another one you need to define it, and the library proj4 can do that for you. You can download it here : https://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/wiki/Download . You will need to add the library and the definition of your projection :

```
<script src="lib/proj4js.js"></script>
<script src="lib/defs/EPSG25830.js"></script>
```

.
Check this website to create your proj4 file (see the link to the proj4 format):
http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/25830/

With that should be able to use the transformations with EPSG 25830

Comment: I will try it.!!!!